# Run as Admin in Vista and 7 c#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to force C# App to run as administrator on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-c-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7)

Hi,
 is it possible to set the "run as Admin" during installation or when the app fist runs can it check to see if this property is set? and if not set it so future runs are as admin?

hope that makes sense

Comment: You can try putting "update" or "setup" in the filename or program description - this causes UAC to require admin permissions even if the program doesn't really need them.

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-c-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7

Comment: I found it out the hard way when programming a Live Update program for my site, that keeps users updated on activity :D I had to just call it LU instead.

Comment: Cool, I don't seem to be able to mark you answer as accepted! is that because its a comment?

Comment: Also thanks OTisler sorry for the dup, the link you gave also seems to work by adding the line to the Manifest. so from not knowing how to do it to two answers. think I'm going to like Stackoverflow!